# JavaScript Building Tic Tac To Automatic Change Score

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am try to build a "Tic Tac Toe" Game. but I have a problem.

Everything works fine except one thing: when the game has ended and all the squares are full with `O` or `X` or when `X`or`O` has won so its will not automatic show it. I have to press one more click on the board to make it work. I really don't know what I can do to make it work.

Thank you!

This is the JavaScript:

```
var count = 1;
var countO = 1;
var countX = 1;


    function resetGame(){
        $('img').attr("src","W.png");
    }

    function resetScore(){

        xScore.innerHTML = "Score X is : 0"
        oScore.innerHTML = "Score O is : 0";
        countO = 1;
        countX = 1;
    }

    if($('img').attr("src") != "W.png" == true){
    alert('hey')
}

    $('.box').on('click', function () {

        if( $('#box1').attr("src")=="X.png"  && $('#box2').attr("src")=="X.png"  && $('#box3').attr("src")=="X.png"  || //Row 1
            $('#box4').attr("src")=="X.png"  && $('#box5').attr("src")=="X.png"  && $('#box6').attr("src")=="X.png"  || //Row 2
            $('#box7').attr("src")=="X.png"  && $('#box8').attr("src")=="X.png"  && $('#box9').attr("src")=="X.png"  ||  //Row 3
            $('#box1').attr("src")=="X.png"  && $('#box4').attr("src")=="X.png"  && $('#box7').attr("src")=="X.png"  ||  // Line 1
            $('#box2').attr("src")=="X.png"  && $('#box5').attr("src")=="X.png"  && $('#box8').attr("src")=="X.png"  ||  // Line 2
            $('#box3').attr("src")=="X.png"  && $('#box6').attr("src")=="X.png"  && $('#box9').attr("src")=="X.png"  ||  // Line 3
            $('#box1').attr("src")=="X.png"  && $('#box5').attr("src")=="X.png"  && $('#box9').attr("src")=="X.png"  || // Cross 1
            $('#box3').attr("src")=="X.png"  && $('#box5').attr("src")=="X.png"  && $('#box7').attr("src")=="X.png"  )  // Cross 2
        {
            xScore.innerHTML = "Score X is : " + countX
            $('img').attr("src","W.png");
            var a = $('#alert1').attr('class', 'alert alert-success');
            $(a).show();
            $(a).html('X is Won!')
            countX++;

        }

        else if( $('#box1').attr("src")=="O.png"  && $('#box2').attr("src")=="O.png"  && $('#box3').attr("src")=="O.png"  || //Row 1
            $('#box4').attr("src")=="O.png"  && $('#box5').attr("src")=="O.png"  && $('#box6').attr("src")=="O.png"  || //Row 2
            $('#box7').attr("src")=="O.png"  && $('#box8').attr("src")=="O.png"  && $('#box9').attr("src")=="O.png"  ||  //Row 3
            $('#box1').attr("src")=="O.png"  && $('#box4').attr("src")=="O.png"  && $('#box7').attr("src")=="O.png"  ||  // Line 1
            $('#box2').attr("src")=="O.png"  && $('#box5').attr("src")=="O.png"  && $('#box8').attr("src")=="O.png"  ||  // Line 2
            $('#box3').attr("src")=="O.png"  && $('#box6').attr("src")=="O.png"  && $('#box9').attr("src")=="O.png"  ||  // Line 3
            $('#box1').attr("src")=="O.png"  && $('#box5').attr("src")=="O.png"  && $('#box9').attr("src")=="O.png"  || // Cross 1
            $('#box3').attr("src")=="O.png"  && $('#box5').attr("src")=="O.png"  && $('#box7').attr("src")=="O.png"  )  // Cross 2
        {
            oScore.innerHTML =  "Score X is : " + countO
            $('img').attr("src","W.png");
            var a = $('#alert1').attr('class', 'alert alert-success');
            $(a).show();
            $(a).html('O is Won!')
            countO++;

        }

    else if(count==1 && $(this).attr("src")=="W.png"){
        $(this).attr("src","X.png");
            count++;
    }

    else if(count==2 && $(this).attr("src")=="W.png") {
            $(this).attr("src", "O.png");
            count--;
        }
    else if($('img').attr("src") != "W.png" == true){
            $('img').attr("src","W.png");
            var b = $('#alert1').attr('class', 'alert alert-info');
            $(b).show();
            $(b).html('Draw!')

    }
    else
        var c = $('#alert1').attr('class', 'alert alert-danger');
        $(c).show();
        $(c).html('Eror : Please fill all the boxes')
    });
```

This is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="xScore"> Score X is : 0</h1>
<h1 id="oScore">Score Y is : 0</h1>
<div id="alert1"></div>


<div id="mainbox">

<div><img id="box1" class="box" src="W.png"></img></div>
<div><img id="box2" class="box" src="W.png"></img></div>
<div><img id="box3" class="box" src="W.png"></img></div>
<div><img id="box4" class="box" src="W.png"></img></div>
<div><img id="box5" class="box" src="W.png"></img></div>
<div><img id="box6" class="box" src="W.png"></img></div>
<div><img id="box7" class="box" src="W.png"></img></div>
<div><img id="box8" class="box" src="W.png"></img></div>
<div><img id="box9" class="box" src="W.png"></img></div>
    <button class="btn-primary" id="btnR" onclick="resetGame()" >Reset Game</button>
    <button class="btn-primary" id="btnS" onclick="resetScore()" >Reset Score</button>


</div>


<script src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"> </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a quick tip: in the first two if (the long ones) try to put contX++ and countY++ int the first line. So if (blah) { countX++; other code...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I think the below two blocks,

```
if(count==1 && $(this).attr("src")=="W.png"){
    $(this).attr("src","X.png");
        count++;
}

else if(count==2 && $(this).attr("src")=="W.png") {
        $(this).attr("src", "O.png");
        count--;
}
```

should be placed before the `if` `else` block where you check the victory of defeat. Because when you check for the victory/defeat you have to make sure that the last move is finished.